# How to make toms played with Stick sound like they were played with Mallets?

Tags: mixing

I need to make the toms I'm look more like tambours played with mallets, any tips, on eq, compression, or effects I could use? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe a transient shaper to take the spike off the head of the sound?

Comment: Definitely try a transient shaper to pull down the attack and raise the sustain. You could also always replace your toms with samples of tambors or similar drums.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess its all about getting rid of that attacky hit of the stick. It contains a high frequency transient, which need to be reduced/removed.

Try using a `multiband compressor` and focus on the upper band (above 2 KHz). Set the `attack` to 0, and the `release` quite fast (less than 5 ms, but you need to tweak this carefully to allow some soft attack to get through). `Ratio` should be high (above 10:1). `Threshold` setting is a matter of levels - you need to see the reduction meter reduce alot for this to work.

Leave the lower compression band(s) untouched.